# How can I create the array using SQL query in presto/hive?

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, presto

There are two records:

| Type | name |
| --- | --- |
| Fruit | Apple |
| Fruit | Orange |

I need below output using sql query in presto:

| Type | name |
| --- | --- |
| Fruit | ["Apple","Orange"] |

How can I write the sql query to get above table?

Comment: can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate function [`array_agg`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html?#array_agg) is designed especially for this purpose:

```sql
--sample data
WITH dataset(type, name) AS (
    VALUES ('Fruit', 'Apple'),
           ('Fruit', 'Orange')
)

-- sample query
SELECT type, array_agg(name) name
FROM dataset
group by type
```

Output:

| type | name |
| --- | --- |
| Fruit | [Apple, Orange] |